# What is the minimum interval for IOS kron?

Tags: cisco-ios

Am I correct that minimum interval for IOS `kron` for reoccurring tasks is 1 minute(`kron occurrence test in 1 recurring`)?

Comment: Please don't forget that you have to *manually* award the bounty to JelmerS

Comment: Done. I tried to do this already earlier, but there was some sort of hold-period for awarding the bounty.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I looked this up in the [Cisco documentation](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/ios-xml/ios/cns/configuration/15-s/cns-15-s-book/cns-cmd-sched.html) and I tested this in IOS 15.3. The smallest reoccurrence for kron is 1 minute.  I tried setting a lower value, but decimal points were not accepted.

`R1(config)#kron occurrence test in 1 recurring`

And this resulted in kron running every minute:

```
R1#show kron schedule 
Kron Occurrence Schedule
test inactive, will run again in 0 days 00:00:00 

R1#show kron schedule 
Kron Occurrence Schedule
test inactive, will run again in 0 days 00:00:59
```